# Glyphicon issue / CORS problems still persist, even after using font_assets and custom defining headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cors

I recently deployed an app -- http://jobs.atlas-china.com

If you go on to http://jobs.atlas-china.com/jobs/2 , you'll notice that the glyphicon for the resume upload does not show up in firefox.

This is because of the Cross Site Header issue. I've tried to fix this by defining a default header, but it's still being wacky.

My application.rb looks like so --

```
module Atlas
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
      'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL',
      'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block',
      'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ENV['APP_URL']
    }
  end
end
```

The font assets are being loaded from cloudfront, so I though this could be a caching issue. However, if I try to make a curl request to the equivalent heroku url, I get --

```
~$ curl -i http://jobs.atlas-china.com/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fcc658a3dec1be1cb0a9bb81f4c7c6de.woff
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: font/x-woff
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 05:13:52 GMT
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 06:51:18 GMT
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Content-Length: 23320
Connection: keep-alive
```

I still don't see anything about an Access-Control-Allow-Origin

What should I be doing here?

**update**

When I make a curl request to the root url, I do see it though!

```
curl -i http://jobs.atlas-china.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://jobs.atlas-china.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 30 May 2014 05:21:10 GMT
Etag: "a73e238bf8cb6ccb7fdf53ae108e11c6"
Server: nginx/1.4.7 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.41
Set-Cookie: _atlas_session=UkVHc0ZSVko2QmdZMWp3djhuelpvUEtMRXVlU1FJclRSN1dpcTR6QWlDS0gyUU15UmdBY0dZWTMya0FtUnFST2RkVnBiWURUdkRTZVJLNk9JcUxlUnZKWHRWaWoxZnZPdThVVTVMMU5qRlpkQnJxUUVBWHQ3WjUreVZ4VENWeTE1WHF3Sit3ZVFQSzMxYmFRVER0aUpsNUN3OW5IOHJQenIzcU9ZcSt5cndwaWlQRXRheVA3dVZMbTVaek5CRFphLS1SNHo4YjlWQ0JXc0U1MlN5R1NjTVlnPT0%3D--0b975a5008287efb7f8114cbcbedd57b34b7d0f9; path=/; HttpOnly
Status: 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.41
X-Request-Id: 964dee7f-d49b-4d68-9a35-f8cd0f6371dc
X-Runtime: 0.147926
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me?

[image]

---

[**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

FYI

Seems like you know already, but CORS is basically a way to protect domains / servers from external AJAX requests. The standard setup is the server will deny requests from external domains automatically, regardless of the headers you send

The way to accept / deny any CORS request is to set the policy options on the Rails server, to allow requests from the domains you want. Rails has a gem to help you do this, called [Rack-CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors):

```
   #config/application.rb
   config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins 'your_domain.com' #-> has to be exact domain
        resource '/your/url', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

I don't know if this will help you or not, but it will certainly give you some ideas as to  how to DRY up your CORS headers, as well as giving you the ability to accept requests as you require

Comment: Thanks for answer Rich. In Firefox, I'm getting the error ->

Comment: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://dqboogrtgpj86.cloudfront.net/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-7531c2bd6e03c07cc2d83fa38e1e2218.ttf

Comment: So this is not happening on your end? Am looking into Rack Cors now. gratitude!

Comment: No problem! I'm using Chrome - it seems to be working for me?